# How to truncate a HTML link?

Tags: sed

INPUT:

```
<a href="docs/2015-05-foobar/foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>
```

OUTPUT

```
<a href="foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>
```

**Question:** How can I remove the "docs/2015-05-foobar/" ? The string could vary between the " 's

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<a href="docs/2015-05-foobar/foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>' |\
  sed 's/\(.*\)href="\(.*\)\/\(.*\)"\(.*\)/\1href="\3"\4/'
```

gives you:

```
<a href="foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>
```

If there is any context, I would however never use `sed` but a proper parser for the HTML to find the `<a>` entry, and then access the `href` of the element found using the access methods provided by the parser.

The `\(.*\)` parts match anything and what they match can be called back with `\1`, `\3`, etc.. The other characters (`href="`, `\/`, `"`) need to be matched (and the slash escaped as it is also used to denote the substitution pattern start and end. The matching is greedy, hence the `\/` matches the last slash before the second `"`. By not using the match part with `\2` that is dropped from the output, just as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ echo '<a href="docs/2015-05-foobar/foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>' |
  sed -e 's,".*/\([^/]*"\),"\1,'
<a href="foobar.sh">foobar.sh</a>
```